# Image on CALayer gets blurry after scaling down then up again

Tags: ios, image

I use an imageView to display an image on a `CALayer`.
After I apply some scaling to it (down to 0.2) using `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale,scale)`, I get ugly blurriness.

It seems like the transformation matrix actually affects the image, rather than have it stored  somewhere in memory in its full res and operating on that.
What might be a way to keep that image details crisp still ?

Thanks!

```
EDIT:
```

Here's the code as asked for

The object inherits from `CALayer`.

```
theScale = 0.2;
trans  = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(theScale,theScale);
[self setAffineTransform:trans];
```

Later on in the code:

```
theScale = 1.0;
trans  = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(theScale,theScale);
[self setAffineTransform:trans];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right.  Core animation doesn't actually animate the object, it takes a "snapshot" and animates that.  The transformation matrix rendering problems are most obviously with apps like flipboard, where the view gets about 4x as blurry when it is transformed.

Comment: post the code in where you call affine transform

Comment: @Ted: this might not help, but try collapsing the 1.0 part to just `[self setAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];`

Comment: Thanks @CodeFi, but this does not help yet :)

Comment: Have you tried setting the `contentsScale` property on the layer? Also, _if_ you are rasterizing the layer have you set the `rasterizationScale` on the layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the issue is blurriness while scaling *down*, have you tried setting CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh); before making your transform?

If the issue is pixelation while scaling *up*, the workaround is having a higher resolution image and *scaling down* instead.

Comment: In what context should I call this function? When creating the image itself ? Or when scaling it ? where exactly ?

Comment: I found the problem. Where I made the the Image in the first place, I used     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext where I should have used     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(aView.bounds.size, NO , 0.0);
Didn't have anything to do with quality, but with old iPhones without retina display apparently. But thanks for the help!